# How does MongoDB know which database to save a schema to?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, mongoose-schema

If I have a schema that looks like this:

```
// create a schema
// This is the User Model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema); // users will be the name of the collection that models get saved to
```

and in another file, I have this inside of a post() function:

```
const User = require("../../models/User");
let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
```

So, although I successfully connected to the MongoDB database in my db.js file like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    console.log("MongoDB Connected...");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    // exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

When I go use the statement `let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });`, how does my program actually know to look in this database? I don't see anywhere that defines mongoose globally or anything inside of the schema file that says to look in the connected database. My only guess is that after connecting, there is code that I don't see that makes sure all of the schemas are associated with the selected database.

Comment: Check connection string it probably contains database name